# nested loops in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why this code:

```
<div ng-app="todoApp">
    <div ng-controller="TodoController">
      <div ng-repeat="obj in arr track by $index">
          {{ obj.name }}
          {{ fn(1) }}
           <div ng-repeat="factor in obj.factors track by $index">
               {{ factor.name }}
               <!-- {{ fn(2) }} -->
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
angular.module('todoApp', [])
    .controller('TodoController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {


    $scope.arr = [{
        "name": "name1",
            "factors": [{
            "name": "factor11"
        }, {
            "name": "factor12"
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "name2",
            "factors": [{
            "name": "factor21"
        }, {
            "name": "factor22"
        }]
    }];

    $scope.fn = function (level) {
        console.log(level);
    };
}]);
```

displays "1" six times instead of twice?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/favmz1bb/1/)

Comment: because you are trying to access object from parent so in the background angular is $watching.

Comment: Please include all the relevant code in your question when asking.

Comment: @Jai, so what i need to do to prevent unnecessary execution of function fn()?

Comment: if you put a debugger; before console.log(level); , then you will be able to see when it is called. Since after the cycles, angular watches the function written in html and executes it to provide the result. Try that.